# How to See List of Active Users Stored in Session Objects on the Admin Page

Tags: asp.net, session

What i am doing is whenever users logs in I store his username in Session Object

Now what i want on the Admin Page is the List of ACTIVE USERS (i.e No of Users which are presently working with the Application (usernames in Session Objects)

Is there any way of doing that..

???

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is. what did u try? how are you storing the usernames at every user login?

Comment: Well.. Just Simply put the username of the logged in person in Session["user"] Object .. Thats it.. For Trying I dont know how get a list of Different Instances of Session Objects for Different Users..

Comment: Store your list of active users in a collection that is accessible across all sessions.  (IE Application state, database, or Cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to Davide Piras, if you are storing `Session["user"] =username` then you are only storing one element since you are always using the same key.

I would put everything in a `List<string>`, for example.

Something like this in your login page:

```
List<string> activeUsers = Cache["ActiveUsers"] as List<string>;
if(activeUsers==null)
   activeUsers = new List<string>();
activeUsers.Add(username_of_person_logged_in);
Cache["active_users"]=activeUsers;
```

Then in your "Admin" page...

```
List<string> activeUsers = Cache["ActiveUsers"] as List<string>;
if(activeUsers!=null)
{
    foreach(var item in activeUsers)
    {
      //do something with them
    }
}
```

**Note:** I changed it to **Cache** since **Cache** is shared across all users. **Session** will not work since it will be only valid on a per-user basis. Thanks to @CheckRaise for his comment.

Comment: Storing the list of active users in session will not persist across all sessions.

Comment: What am I saying, @CheckRaise. Of course not! Editing my answer immediately before I get Downvote party going on here.!

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` object cannot be accessed outside of its own session. If you need an administrator to be able to see all the active sessions, you need to use the `Application` object. For example, in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Application["Users"] = new List<string>;
}
```

Then, to add a user (possibly when they click 'Log in'):

```
Application.Lock();
((List<string>)Application["Users"]).Add(username);
Application.UnLock();
```

You should also remove the user in `Session_End`:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Application.Lock();
  ((List<string>)Application["Users"]).Remove(username);
  Application.UnLock();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James .. But what code do i need to write on the admin page .. to access the List<string> Application Object

Comment: You can retrieve the list: `var users = (List<string>)Application["Users"];`. Then do what you like with it. For example: `foreach (var s in users) Response.Write(s + "<br />");`

Comment: suppose user closes the window without logging-out then how to detect and show current active users on site/page??